# How to stop execution of particular quartz job when it is running?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am implementing the **quartz job** scheduling by code. Below is my method to schedule and reschedule the quartz job.

```
void setJobSchedular(ScraperSearchOnRequest scraperSearchOnRequestInstance) {
        try {
            String groupName = "Scraper Group" + scraperSearchOnRequestInstance?.id
            String jobName = "ScraperOnRequestJob"
            Scheduler scheduler = getJobManagerService().quartzScheduler

            JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, groupName);
            //create JobDetail and Trigger
            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(com.dogmasystems.scraper.ScraperOnRequestJob1.class).withIdentity(jobKey).build();

            //add passing parameters to JobDataMap for first JobDetail
            jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("id", scraperSearchOnRequestInstance?.id?.toString());
            jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("groupName", groupName);

            if (scheduler.checkExists(jobKey)) {
                println("Rescheduling the old job having group name " + groupName)
                Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger(new TriggerKey(jobName, groupName))
                TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();
                Trigger newTrigger = tb.startAt(scraperSearchOnRequestInstance.scheduledTime).usingJobData("id",
                        scraperSearchOnRequestInstance?.id?.toString()).build()
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.key, newTrigger);
            } else {
                println("Scheduling the new job having group name " + groupName)
                SimpleTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(jobName, groupName)
                        .startAt(scraperSearchOnRequestInstance.scheduledTime).usingJobData("id",
                        scraperSearchOnRequestInstance?.id?.toString()).build();
                scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            println("**********************Error in setJobSchedular for scraperOnRequestJob****************************")
            e.printStackTrace("Error while setting ScraperOnRequestJob " + e.printStackTrace())
            println("******************************************************")
        }
    }
```

Basically my job is running at specified time and it is working fine using the above method.

**Requirement:**

1. I want to stop my running job execution by clicking the **STOP** button at UI using the ajax call.

[image]

**For stopping the job** i am giving **jobName** and **groupName** of that particular job.

```
void stopSchedularJob(String id) throws Exception {
        String groupName = "Scraper Group" + id
        String jobName = "ScraperOnRequestJob"
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, groupName);
        TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey(jobName, groupName);
        Scheduler scheduler = getJobManagerService().quartzScheduler
        Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey)
        if (trigger) {
            println "Trigger key name to stop " + triggerKey.getName()
            // wait long enough to see the job execution
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000); //1 minute
            scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey)
            println "The ScraperOnRequestJob having " + groupName + " has been stopped."
        } else {
            println "No trigger could be found for " + triggerKey.getName()
        }

    }
```

**But it is giving me error:**

```
Error |
2019-11-21 11:20:10,411 [http-bio-8078-exec-2] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
  Where: while updating tuple (0,36) in relation "scraper_search"
Error |
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
  Where: while updating tuple (0,36) in relation "scraper_search"; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
  Where: while updating tuple (0,36) in relation "scraper_search"
```

I tried many solutions like

1. `scheduler.interrupt(jobKey)`
2. `scheduler.shutdown()` (I only want to kill only particular job, not all the jobs)
3. Quartz Job Listeners

But still i am not able to find the particular solution.

Comment: https://www.javarticles.com/2016/07/quartz-interrupt-job-example.html

Comment: Are your jobs stored in a database ? Can you provide the quartz scheduler configuration that you have ?

Comment: With `scheduler.interrupt(jobKey)` have you actually implemented `InterruptableJob` interface on `com.dogmasystems.scraper.ScraperOnRequestJob1`?

Comment: please give details on your scheduler configuration: the errors does not seam to be sent by quartz

Comment: I think interrupt job will not break the execution of running job.

Comment: what is this UI? is it something you built yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Calling scheduler.interrupt(jobKey) will not terminate the execution of the running job.
You can find the documentation [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/InterruptableJob.html)

An example of how to interrupt a running job [here](https://github.com/Flipkart/quartz/blob/master/distribution/examples/src/main/java/org/quartz/examples/example7/DumbInterruptableJob.java)

Comment: It would be nice if you post the example right here. Please don't post only links on other sites.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [timer task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) also for scheduling tasks. So that you can easily create and terminate them.

> public abstract class TimerTask extends Object implements Runnable
>   * A task that can be scheduled for one-time or repeated execution by a Timer.

As per your requirement used `Hashtable` to store timer-obj with a key for future purpose.

```java
public class TimerTasks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException, IOException {

        Timer timerObj = new Timer();
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask(); // This task is scheduled to run every 10 seconds

        startTimer("T1", timerObj, myTask, 2, 10000);

            System.out.println("Enter Something to stop Timer.");
            System.in.read();
            System.in.read();

        terminateTimer("T1");

        System.out.println("Main end.");
    }

    static Map<String, Timer> taskGroup = new Hashtable<String, Timer>();
    public static String startTimer(String key, Timer timerObj, TimerTask task, long delay, long period) {
        if (taskGroup.containsKey(key)) {
            return "Fialure, On this key alreay timer is available.";
        } else {
            timerObj.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
            // You can save multiple, from key get timer object and you can cancel.
            taskGroup.put(key, timerObj);
            return "Success";
        }

    }
    public static void terminateTimer(String key) {
        if (taskGroup.containsKey(key)) {
            Timer timer = taskGroup.get("T1");
            // This task has been cancelled (with a call to TimerTask.cancel).
            timer.cancel();
            taskGroup.remove(key);
        }
    }
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask{
    public MyTask(){
        //Some stuffs
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hi, see its Timer task.");
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to do it using quartz scheduler only.